# Py/Tk Grid don't behave property

Tags: python, tkinter

Grid on Tkinter does not resize controls properly. Here is my code:

```
menubar = Menu(frm)
txt = Text(frm)
def TxtTupleLineCol():
    str = txt.index(INSERT)
    return tuple(str.split(sep='.'))
scrl = Scrollbar(frm, command=txt.yview)
scrl.grid(column=1, sticky=(E + N + S))
txt.config(yscrollcommand=scrl.set)
txt['wrap'] = WORD
scrlw = Scrollbar(frm, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=txt.xview)
scrlw.grid(row=1, sticky=(S + E + W))
st = StatusBar(frm)
tu  = TxtTupleLineCol()
st.variable.set(('Linha:' + tu[-2] + ' Coluna:' + tu[-1]))
txt.config(xscrollcommand=scrlw.set)
txt.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
st.grid(row=2, sticky=S + E + W)
filen = Cfg("")
frm.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frm.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
frm.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
frm.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frm.grid_propagate(False)
```

If I resize the window, it spaces between scroll and text. #FIXME?(in another partof code I added that row/col config./ portuguese doesn't affect understanding.)

Comment: In your recent edit, you added a weight to both columns. You don't want to do that. You only want the column with the text widget to have a weight. The weight means "let me expand to fill extra space", and you only want the text widget to expand. If two columns have the same weight, they will both expand an equal amount to fill extra space, yielding a scrollbar with a lot of extra space around it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't run, but judging from what I see it appears you aren't giving your rows or columns any weight, which is usually what causes "doesn't resize properly" problems when using grid. Most likely, adding something like this will fix the problem:

```
frm.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: I wrote:
>in another partof code I added that row/col config.

Comment: @Carlos: Rest assured, tkinter works properly with respect to resizing. If your program isn't resizing properly you are doing something wrong. If you don't show us all your code it is impossible for us to guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @Carlos: I don't understand "Propagating grid is wrong?". Are you asking about turning propagation off? If so, there's nothing right or wrong about it. Turning propagation off will definitely change how your app behaves, however.